# SwiftUI BaseUnit implementation custom measurement

Tags: swift, swiftui, dimension, measurement

For calculating the pressure drop in a pipe, I use a pipe class with a flow parameter. I would like to implement a custom measurement for a flow rate, but I get an "exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** You must override baseUnit in your class ... to define its base unit.'" error.

My code for the flow unit dimension is:

```
class UnitFlow: Dimension {
    static let cubicMeterPerSecond = UnitFlow(symbol: "m3/s", converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1.0))
    static let cubicMeterPerMinute = UnitFlow(symbol: "m3/min", converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 60.0))
    static let cubicMeterPerHour = UnitFlow(symbol: "m3/h", converter: 
    //et cetera
          
    static let baseUnit = UnitFlow(symbol: "m3/s", converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1.0))
}
```

Where it goes wrong is in this line:

```
Text("\(pipe.flow.converted(to: UnitFlow.cubicMeterPerMinute).value)")
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is use case of your code?

Comment: The use case is that the pipe flow (i.e. pipe.flow2) is converted form one unit to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggests, you need to override `baseUnit`. However, this is a method - not a variable.

Remove your current `baseUnit`, and replace it with the following:

```
class UnitFlow: Dimension {
    /* ... */

    override class func baseUnit() -> Self {
        Self(symbol: "m3/s")
    }
}
```

Comment: @etri Don't forget to accept the answer if it was useful!

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Pity it wasn't so arduous to give Apple feedback on their docs as it seems incorrect in their sample code…

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this because I just had a similar issue. However, `Self(symbol: "m3/s")` will initialize your converter to ZERO and then when or if you use `.baseUnit()` the value will come out to be ZERO.

```
class UnitFlow: Dimension {
    static let cubicMeterPerSecond = UnitFlow(symbol: "m3/s",
                                              converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1.0))
    static let cubicMeterPerMinute = UnitFlow(symbol: "m3/min",
                                              converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 60.0))
          
    override class func baseUnit() -> Self {
        return cubicMeterPerSecond as! Self
   }
}
```

The thing I don't like about this is the force-casting as Self, but I haven't found a solution to this. If anyone has a solution to that part, it would be amazing.

Edit: Using the following method is the way I've decided to implement this in my project. It will still result in a fatal error if something goes wrong with the conversion, but at least there will be a better reason:

```
/// A unit for a measurement of Work.
open class UnitWork: Dimension {
    /// Joule = Newton*meter
    public static let joules = UnitWork(symbol: "J", converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1.0))
    public static let newtonMeter = UnitWork(symbol: "N m", converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1.0))

    public override class func baseUnit() -> Self {
        guard let work = joules as? Self else { fatalError("Cannot get base unit for: \(Self.Type.self)")}
        return work
    }
}
```